# what is the proper coding to add python-mode plugin to _vimrc

Tags: python-3.x

Would someone be kind enough to show me what exact code is needed in the _vimrc file to get the Python-mode plugin to work! Thanks! (I also read that it is out-dated) is the Jedi plugin that much better? Thanks from the VIM newbie!!!

Bob

Comment: This really belongs on superuser, also check https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/

Answer (score 0):

You won't be lucky if you expect a single command in your virmrc. Turning vim into a python ide is a collection of multiple plugins you can either manage by hand or use a plugin manager like vundle. Best practice is to use your configuration along with a repository hosted for example on github using git. You can use mercurial or baazar just as well.

Walking through one of the numerous tutorials on the net will be your only chance.
For example here: https://github.com/mbrochh/vim-as-a-python-ide along with the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g